# How to fetch data from dropdown selection and display it on the same HTML page? Django

Tags: python, django

I am doing a project management tool web application. I would like user can choose 'user' from dropdown selection, click 'Add member', then the member will show somewhere under the member?. Here is what I am doing.

[image: Here is what I am doing]

Please do not worry about the styling. I have not done UI yet.

view.py

```
def member_select(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        selection = request.GET.get('id',None)
        if selection:
            selected_member = User.objects.filter(pk=selection)
            return selected_member
```

project_index.html

```
 <form action="" method="GET" id="selection-form">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                    <select id="member_list">
                            {% for user in user %}
                        <option>
                            {{ user.username }}
                        </option>
                            {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                     <input type="button" value="Add member" id="selection-button">
                     </form>
```

base.html

```
 <script>
      var url = $( '#selection-form' ).attr( 'action' );
        $("selection-button").onclick(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:url,
                data:{
                    id:$('#member_list').val()
                },
                success:function (result) {
                    alert('okay');
                },
                error:function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                }

            });
        });

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an empty `<p class='member-name'><p>` and 
after choosing in the jquery success function 
change to

```
  success:function (result) {
                $('.member-name').text(result);

            },
```

Comment: `$('.member-name').text(result);` did you add the '.' because I did a typo error

try sending the `selected_member.name` in the responce
and try to `alert(responce)` to see if it gives you back the member's name

Comment: @ Sue-May Xu what does the `alert(responce)` says

Comment: not sure where I was wrong, when I click the button, nothing shows up.

Comment: @Sue-MayXu `form action="" method="GET" id="selection-form` the form action is empty so the js doesnt get the url 
did you try debugging the view `print("member select")` underneath `def member_select(request):` just to check if activates the function

Comment: yes. I print('selected_member') under def member_select(request): , but nothing shows up @Kostadin Slavov

Answer (score 0):

try this (not fully tested)

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse
def member_select(request):
    selection = request.GET.get('id',None)
    if selection:
        data = serializers.serialize('json',User.objects.filter(pk=selection))
    else:
        data = {}
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

from the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/

In javascript ajax funtion the response should be a user object if exists or empty json string

```
<form action="" method="GET" id="selection-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="member_list">
       {% for user in user %}
          <option value="{{user.pk}}">{{ user.username }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
     </select>
     <input type="button" value="Add member" id="selection-button">
  </form>
   <di id='res'></div>


  $("#selection-button").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var value =$('#member_list').val(); 
      $.ajax({
         type:'GET',
         url:'.',
         data:{
             id:value
         },
         success:function (result) {
            alert('okay');
            $('#res').append(result);
            console.info(result);
         },
         error:function (result) {
              alert('error');
         }
       });
     });
```

Comment: what is content_type ? this did not work :/. @Dimitris Kougioumtzis

Comment: yes because the id in your javascript function is wrong  (typo) change it to  $("#selection-button").  The content type tells django function that the response from the request is a json object

Comment: I changed it to '#selection_button', but still does not work

Comment: @Sue-May Xu i edited my answer and i added a div res so to display the result of the ajax inside that div. So when you run it  the result from ajax should display inside the div.

Comment: How to display 'username' instead of user 'id'? For right now, it only shows id. Btw, how to store these data into database ? Since all the information is gone when I refresh the page.  @Dimitris Kougioumtzis